# How to change ProxyMesh headers default timeout configuration

Tags: http, proxy, header

Is it possible to change the default timeout configuration (20 seconds) to less by adding header to the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass X-ProxyMesh-Timeout in the headers. More info coudl be found here:
https://proxymesh.com/blog/pages/proxy-server-headers.html